Upgrading ASP.NET Core 3.1 to .NET 8 won't launch anymore
After upgrading my ASP.NET Core 3.1 application to .NET 8, I'm not able to launch my application anymore. As I can't find anything on the documentation for it and neither can find any usage of it, I wonder why it's complaining about this one:

System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IHttpSendFileFeature' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.BrowserLinkMiddleware.ExecuteWithFilter(IHttpSocketAdapter injectScriptSocket, String requestId, HttpContext httpContext)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.BrowserLinkMiddleware.ExecuteWithFilter(IHttpSocketAdapter injectScriptSocket, String requestId, HttpContext httpContext)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.BrowserLinkMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.BrowserRefreshMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()

As I just got the application assigned and not familiar that much with ASP.NET Core, I hope someone can hint me in the right direction.

A similar issue posted on Github here - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/34053.
Seems to be related to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink package - does your project have a reference to this package?

Yes it does but not sure why. As said older project I just got handed over and should upgrade, not very comfy with ASP Core stuff.

In that case, I'd try removing the package reference from your project and seeing if that fixes the issue. The package is showing as deprecated on nuget - https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.web.browserlink/. Note that you'll probably encounter a number of issues when upgrading a project by so many versions - each major update will introduce a number of breaking changes which you may need to find workarounds for - you just need to work through them until you can build, and then give it a good thorough test.

Thanks. That worked. And it's not just upgrading.. the project was before hosted on a IIS with a MSSQL Database and should now be migrated to a Debian server with MySQL. So there is a lot of work left anyway. :)
